# jquery - dynamically loading/unloading your code

Tags: jquery

Situation: You are trying to test some javascript at the middle/end of some long process (e.g. a long painful multiustep form) and instead reloading the page and filling out the form again you'd like some way to dynamically reload your script.

My rudimentary solution :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#downloadPdf").click( function(e) {
        var url = '/teachers/pdf.js';
        var success;

                // unbind the current click
        $("#downloadPdf").unbind('click');

                // reload your script
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: success
        });

                // this is the regular part of your code
})
```

Obviously this is easy to do if you have not very much code, but if you have a lot more code I could see this getting messy. Any better suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a click handler instead of .live(), you could clone the elements that will be effected and remove the old ones before you re-run your edited code